# Applescript display buttons on touch bar?

Tags: macos, applescript, macbookpro-touch-bar

Applescript has a `display dialog` function in which one can summon a pop-up, and by using `buttons {"x","y","z"}` one can add custom buttons to the dialog. Is there a way to get these buttons to appear on the touch bar as well, as pop-ups typically do?